# How can I remove color cast created by a defective scanner?

Tags: post-processing, scanning, color-correction

I scanned my photo using an HP Scanjet scanner, but scanner CCD sensor has a problem and the result is a scanned image as below:

[image: Scanned Image]

As you can see in the image, there is additional color cast. Is it possible to remove this color cast in Adobe Photoshop? If so, how?

---

***Edit***
[Bart Arondson](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9161/bart-arondson) give good solution but it damage image texture and color.
[image]
is there better way??

Answer (score 5):

That is not a colour cast. A colour cast is an overall tint or bias *toward* a certain colour. This can be fixed by pushing the colour balance the other way. The image you posted is simply **missing the red channel entirely**. Regular techniques to shift the colour balance wont work as there is no red* to boost

This cannot be fixed unless you fill in the missing data somehow.

* my initial diagnosis of missing red channel was based on the cyan background, cyan is 0% red, 100% green 100% blue, which is exactly what you get when you start with a white (100/100/100) background and drop (zero) the red values. However upon examination, there is data in the red channel but it's corrupt / not what you would expect to find.

---

Ok, so what can you do? Images of faces have very little blue data, so the only good data we have is the green channel by itself, which is effectively a greyscale image.

A skilled photoshop artist could recolour a greyscale image, but that's a complex process. The only thing that can be done simply is apply a skin colour to the whole image.

Another option is to attempt to rebuild the red channel somehow. Here I've rebuilt the red channel using the channel mixer using 60% of the original red channel and adding 60% of the green channel.

[image]

Given the aforementioned lack of colour information in the other channels this is really akin to applying a single colour to a greyscale image (though it does preserve a small amount of information from the otherwise defunct red channel). Using curves to blacken the hair a bit and reducing saturation yeilds this result, which is about as good as you will get without manually masking and recolouring each area!

[image]

Comment: this is not matter `what the hell is that!!!!` can i remove this colors without affect on photo texture??

Comment: @JesonPark the point is that colour casts are fixable, this isn't. You are missing vital colour information, if you remove the (cyan/red) colours you do see, you'll be left with no colour at all!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best practice, but it gets rid of the cyan background.

1. Open the image in Photoshop
2. Duplicate the layer (so you'll have a backup)
3. Go to `Image -> Adjustments -> Replace Color...
4. Set the `Fuzziness` to ±15.
5. With the `Add to sample` color picker (the one with the + sign) sample the color at different locations in the background such that you only get the background color in your selection, not the face:
   [image]
6. In the `Replacement` part of the window change the `Lightness` to +100. This will replace the selected color range with white.
   [image]
7. Additionally you can play with the `Fuzziness` slider to remove the blue cast from the face as well.
8. Hit `OK` in the Replace Color window.

Result:
[image]

Comment: tnx....excellence answer

Comment: This still leaves the color cast on the face though. Over all, there's a cyan cast to the image, so background elimination doesn't really fix the image.

Comment: JoanneC: Yes...answer is good but not for face and clothing....it cant remove color from my face and my cloth and by this way image become damaged

Comment: This is no mere colour cast, the entire red channel is missing / corrupted! No simple technique is going to fix the image.

Comment: I agree with @MattGrum - I tried a few avenues in PS with zero luck. At best it could be usable by black and white conversion.

Comment: JoanneC: I'm aware of that, but the original question seemed to ask how to remove the blue/cyan color, i.e. the cyan background. I see it is now edited to `color cast` changing the scope to the whole image.

Comment: @BartArondson - It asked about removing the color, but it's in the face as well. As Matt noted, though, it's not really a cast, it's just a corrupted image.

Comment: JoanneC: How can i solve my problem with black and white conversion ???

Comment: @JesonPark - You won't solve it, you just might make it usable as a black and white photo. Follow the same steps a Bart described, but also move the saturation slide to -100. Not great, the scanner is clearly broken, but might give you something.

Comment: @JesonPark Basically you are dealing with an image that is effectively grey scale but with some random red values that give the impression of colour. So you already have a greyscale image more or less, so you might as well remove the incorrect colours you see. The only other option is to generate some meaningful colour data some how.